# For inside for to print "table" in java (for beginners)

Tags: java, loops

I am new to Java. I want to print this table using a nested for loop.

[image]

My program is currently not printing anything. What am I missing?

```js
class ex38 {     
    public static void main (String[] args) {
 for(int i=1;i==3;i++) {
     for(int j=1;j==i;j++) {
  System.out.print(j*i + " ");
     }
     System.out.print("\n");
 }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm leaning more towards "typo" here, but `i == 3` and `j == i` are always going to be false, meaning you'll never loop.

Comment: To @Makoto and the close voters: I would argue that this is more likely a misunderstanding of the conditional of the `for` loop than a typo. I'm thinking OP was thinking the loop terminates when the conditional evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @JonathanLam:  I would take umbrage to this, given that [this is quite clearly spelled out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) in the Java trails, or any other introductory material.  From the perspective of a Stack Overflow question, it reads like it's a typo.

Comment: @JonathanLam is right. I was so concerned about the logic of the code and afraid it was actually getting stuck in an infinite loop that I didnt realize the misuse of the conditional clause. Thanks for pointing how basic the solution is.

Answer (score 2):

As @Makoto said in his comment, the conditional clause of the `for` loops are always 
 false. The loop runs only if these conditions are true.

Try using `i <= 3` and `j <= i` instead. This will mean that it will generate n rows, with each row containing n items. (In this case n = 3)

(For a more thorough explanation of `for` loop syntax, you can check out [Oracle's docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) on it. It uses the term "termination" clause and states: "When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.")

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the chapter about for loops again :-). The second one of the arguments you give to for(), is the condition that has to be true for the loop to run. Since you you want to run it, while i is less than, or equal to 3, you have to specify that condition.

In your outer loop you need to replace i == 3 with i <= 3.

In your inner loop, you need to replace j == i with j <= i.